# form a subgroup by picking simultaneously 3 students among a group of 8 students, how many subgroups we can make?

Tags: combinatorics

I am just a bit puzzled by this question even when it is easy:

"How to form a subgroup by picking simultaneously 3 students among a group of 8 students. How many different subgroups can we form?"

Do we put back those 3 students when we pick them? Is that the default meaning?

Comment: The question is asking how many ways there are to select three of the eight students when the order of selection does not matter.  Since the students are selected simultaneously, the students are selected without replacement.

Comment: To me, it is not quite clear whether the question is asking how many teams of three can be made from the 8 students, or whether how many triples can be formed from 8, like how many possible pairings of 2n socks

Answer (score 0):

No. I don't think we put the students back. The question seem to be asking for the number of ways to choose $3$ distinct students out of $8$. For a moment let us forget that we pick the students simultaneously, and count the number of ways to pick $3$ distinct students one by one. Note that firstly, we have $8$ choices for which student we pick first. For the second student, we have $7$ choices, as we cannot pick the first student again. For the third student we have $6$ choices. Let the students chosen be $\{A, B, C\}$. For each such set of students, you can choose them in $3!=6$ ways. For instance, the set $\{A, B, C\}$ is counted $6$ times as $(A, B, C), (A, C, B), (B, A, C), (B, C, A), (C, A, B)$ and $(C, B, A)$. To get rid of this error, we can divide the total number by $6$. Thus, we get $\frac{8\times7\times6}{6}=56$ ways.